Bound on moments implies subgamma random variable (from Boucheron, Lugosi & Massart 2013)
The book 1, defines a centred random variable $X$ to be a subgamma random variable with parameters $(\nu, c)$ if
$$
\log \mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X} \leq \frac{\nu \lambda^2}{2(1-c|\lambda|)} \quad \text{for all $\lambda \in (-1/c, 1/c)$}\,. 
$$
Their Theorem 2.3 states that if for some positive constants $A$ and $B$, $\mathbb{E} X^{2q} \leq q! A^q + (2q)! B^{2q}$, then $X$ is subgamma with parameters $(4(A+B^2), 2B)$. There is a step or two in their proof that I am struggling to justify. The proof proceeds as follows:
Let $X'$ be an independent copy of $X$. Then,
$$
 Ee^{\lambda X} E e^{-\lambda X} = \sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q} E[(X-X')^{2q}]}{(2q)!}\,.
$$
By convexity, $E[(X-X')^{2q}] \leq 2^{2q} E[X^{2q}]$. Using this and our assumption on $E[X^{2q}]$, we have that
$$
Ee^{\lambda X} E e^{-\lambda X} \leq \sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q} 2^{2q} (A^q q! + B^{2q} (2q)!)}{(2q)!}\,.
$$
Now, the authors claim to use that $q!/(2q)! \leq 2^{-q}/q!$ (agreed) and that $E X = 0$ implies $E e^{-\lambda X} \geq 1$ (agreed), to conclude that for any $\lambda$ such that $2B|\lambda| < 1$,
$$
E e^{\lambda X} \leq e^{2A\lambda^2} + \frac{4B^2 \lambda^2}{1-4B^2\lambda^2}\,.
$$
I am not happy with how to get this assertion. The following is my attempt to recreate it, which goes wrong. Using that $E e^{-sX} \geq 1$,
$$
E e^{sX} \leq E e^{sX} E e^{-sX} \leq \underbrace{\sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q} 2^{2q} A^q q!}{(2q)!}}_{=:S_1} + \underbrace{\sum_{q=0}^\infty (4B^2 \lambda^2)^q}_{=:S_2}\,.
$$
Now, for $S_1$ everything works out. Using $q!/(2q)! \leq 2^{-q}/q!$, we have that
$$
S_1 \leq \sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q} 2^q A^q}{q!} = e^{2A\lambda^2}\,.
$$
For $S_2$, let $x = 4B^2 \lambda^2$ and note that $x < 1$. Using the formula for a geometric series,
$$
S_2 = \sum_{q=0}^\infty x^q = \frac{1}{1-x} \quad \text{that is,} \quad S_2 = \frac{1}{1-4B^2 \lambda^2}\,,
$$
and since $4B^2 \lambda^2 < 1$,
$$
S_2 > \frac{4B^2\lambda^2}{1-4B^2\lambda^2}.
$$
How does one get the tighter bound they have? The right-hand side just above?
1 "Concentration inequalities: a nonasymptotic theory of independence", Boucheron, Lugosi & Massart 2013
Screenshot of this part of the book:


The derivation as written in the book is indeed incorrect as you have noticed.  It can be fixed by splitting out the first term of the sum at an earlier stage:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda X}]\mathbf{E}[e^{-\lambda X}]
&= \sum_{q=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q}\mathbf{E}[(X - X')^{2q}]}{(2q)!} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^{2q}\mathbf{E}[(X - X')^{2q}]}{(2q)!} \\
\end{align*}
and then going through the rest of the derivation, eventually recombining the extra $+1$ term into the $S_1$ sum.  This way the $S_2$ sum starts at $q=1$ instead of $0$.
